# Why does weak interaction violate time reversal symmetry?

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, weak-interaction, time-reversal-symmetry

Is there a theoretical explanation (or model)  which explains the violation of time reversal symmetry by weak interaction, or it is simply an empirical fact?

Comment: In quantum field theory, the combination of, the time-reversal symmetry $T$, the space-reflection symmetry $P$, and the charge conjugation symmetry $C$ (exchange particles and anti-particles), $CPT$ is always obeyed. In the weak interaction, $CP$ symmetry is violated, meaning that the time-reversal symmetry $T$ is also violated.

Comment: Regarding why $CP$ symmetry is violated, you can find explanations in any particle physics textbook. Basically, it is due to the complex phases in the CKM and PMNS matrix.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by *explanation*? The standard model predicts T-violation (cf @WeinEld's comments), but that model has lots of free parameters that we can adjust without disturbing its basic structure (as long as we don't mind breaking its agreement with experiment, of course). Are you asking if all of those mild variations of the standard model still predict T-violation? Or (same idea) are you asking if there is some other model that also agrees with experiment but that has a more rigid structure? Just trying to understand what you mean by *explanation*.

Comment: I use the term "explanation"  according to your second definition, i.e. a theory with few free parameters, and  whith a  sufficiently rigid  structure. I haven' t yet studied QFT in depth, but reading my particle physics book (at undergraduate level) I'm  wondering why just the weak interaction violates T-symmetry, what is special about it, that make it violate T-symmetry?

Comment: Maybe it is the other way around: *because* the weak force violates P and T (just so; it is special), we can detect it clearly despite its weakness, since it is the *only* force that does that.

Comment: Ok, and the "rarity" of this violation is predictable theoretically?

Comment: No! Absolutely not. Like most features of the standard model (the standard theory, really), it describes a "just so" fact of the ground. Theoretical "predictions" are vastly overhyped: they are just mere conceptual connections.